# Am I taking the correct approach towards creating a dropdown list with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is just something I threw together while working on a Tumblr blog theme earlier today, and I want to know if I'm taking the correct approach at it. It seems to be working for me but is there any preferred method for creating a drop down?

I'm using jQuery for this just because it's so much easier than JS.

My HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=main.css >
    <script src=jquery.js ></script>
    <script src=script.js ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <h3 id=title>Click</h3>
      <ul id=list-parent >
        <li class=element >element</li>
        <li class=element >element</li>
        <li class=element >element</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
#list-parent {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: orange;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

.element {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  background: #88f;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clicks = 1;

  $('#list-parent').css({
    height: '0px',
    padding: '0px 5px'
  });

  $('#title').click(function(){
    var height = $('#list-parent').children().length * 20;

    if (clicks === 1){
      $('#list-parent').animate({
        height: height + 'px',
        padding: '5px'
      });

      clicks ++ ;
    } else if(clicks === 2){
      $('#list-parent').animate({
        height: '0px',
        padding: '0px 5px'
      });
      clicks = 1;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: *Note* Questions about *"is this a good way to do X"*? Tend to be off-topic for StackOverflow, as the site is for problems with code, not opinions on working solutions.

Comment: This may be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have several different approaches for creating a drop-down, I wouldn't say there is a definitive *"right"* and *"wrong"* way to do so. That being said the code you currently have can be cleaned up and simplified to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#list-parent').hide();

  $('#title').click(function(){
    $("#list-parent").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

---

To expand your functionality (for having sub-dropdowns) have the item `#title` be a class `.drop`. And have the structure be the element directly after a `drop` is their list. That way you can have several dropdowns inside dropdowns, for example with the structure:

```
  <h3 class=drop>Click</h3>
  <ul class=list-parent >
    <li class=element >element</li>
    <li class=element >
      <div class=drop>Click</div>
      <ul class=list-parent >
        <li class=element >element</li>
        <li class=element >element</li>
      </ul>
    </li>        
    <li class=element >element</li>
  </ul>
```

You would do:

```
$('.list-parent').hide();

$('.drop').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vp1v2zhm/2/)